# javascript : function parameters passing?

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

My code is as follows:

The "data" is:

[{"DESCRIPTION":"sf","Name":"Tom","Date":"2014-07-08 10:19:29.0","PICTURES":[]},{"DESCRIPTION":"sf","Name":"Tom","Date":"2014-07-08 10:23:33.0","PICTURES":[]},{"DESCRIPTION":"dfs","Name":"Tom","Date":"2014-07-08 10:27:20.0","PICTURES":[]},{"DESCRIPTION":"sfd","Name":"Tom","Date":"2014-07-08 10:31:35.0","PICTURES":[{"PICTURE":"C:\Users\hanlu Feng\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\ServletHtml\pictures\Tom\2014-07-08-10-31-35\2012042622442667.jpg"},{"PICTURE":"C:\Users\hanlu Feng\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\ServletHtml\pictures\Tom\2014-07-08-10-31-35\833344_1071288421.jpg"}]}]

```
//Code 1 

function dynamicReport(data){
    var table = document.getElementById("erroreport");
    if(table.rows.length==0){
        for(var i=0;i<=data.length;i++){
            if(i==0){
            var row = table.insertRow(0);
            var cell = row.insertCell(0);
            cell.innerHTML = titleName;
            cell = row.insertCell(1);
            cell.innerHTML = titleTime;
            cell = row.insertCell(2);
            cell.innerHTML = titleDescription;
            cell = row.insertCell(3);
            cell.innerHTML = titleImages;
            }else{
                var row = table.insertRow(i);
                var cell = row.insertCell(0);
                cell.innerHTML= data[i-1].Name;
                cell = row.insertCell(1);
                cell.innerHTML = data[i-1].Date;
                var description = data[i-1].DESCRIPTION;
                if(description.length>7){
                    description = description.substring(0,7)+"..."
                }
                cell = row.insertCell(2);
                cell.innerHTML=description;
                var userName = data[i-1].Name;
                var reportTime= data[i-1].Date;
                var url = "selectionShow";
                var p ="<p><u><font  size='2' color='blue' onclick='requestPictures("+url+"," +userName+", "+reportTime+")' style='cursor:pointer'>Check Pcitures</font></u></p>";
                cell = row.insertCell(3);
                cell.innerHTML = p;
            }//end else

        }//end for
    }//end if
}

    // code 2

function requestPictures(listUrl,name,time){
    var var1=name;
    var var2 = time;
    $.ajax({
        cache : false,
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        url : listUrl,
        //data : $("#ajaxFrm").serialize(), 
        data : {command:"images","name":name,"time":time},
        async : false,
        error : function(request) {
            waidAni();
            if(request.status ==202){
                alert(request.responseText);
            }else
            alert("Request Error");
        },
        success : function(data) {
            waidAni();          
            //alert(data);
            window.location.href= data;



        }
    });

}
```

When I debug it ,there is a error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number ".
I think the error is in the code:

```
var p ="<p><u><font  size='2' color='blue' onclick='requestPictures("+url+"," +userName+", "+reportTime+")' style='cursor:pointer'>Check Pcitures</font></u></p>";
```

I tried many methods ,it doesn't work. And I use the method in this link:
[parameters passing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24QmE.png)

The error still exists.I don't know why?

I want to create a table just like this:
[image]

Comment: Unless `url`, `userName` and `reportTime` are all numbers, your inline event handler is a disaster.

Comment: This code is terrible. Why do you need that inline thing? Where is it used?

Comment: Can you post the whole code? The bit you posted is fine: http://jsfiddle.net/QL4L4/ syntax wise.

Comment: What are you using `p` for?  Since you're already using jQuery you might as well create and object and add the click handler, then append it to whatever container you plan to put it into.

Comment: After update - your code is still fine (syntax wise). What the error is saying is that JS parser can't compile your code. By any chance you don't have it like like `var p = "<p><u><font size="2" color='blue'`, etc?

Comment: Well, your values need quotes.  Just focusing on the onclick, change it to this:  "... onclick='requestPictures(\""+url+"\",\""+userName+"\",\"" + reportTime + "\")' ..."

Answer (score 0):

First of all, my solution will not include the inline styles, font tags, or underline tags.  I would recommend that you put all this in a class.

Instead of inserting pure html, you should create an object, bind the click event, then append it to the cell.

```
var p = $("<p class='picture-link'>Check Pictures</p>");
p.click(function(){requestPictures(url, userName, reportTime);});
$(cell).append(p);
```

This is how I would do it.

As I said you'll have to create the class

[Here is a fiddle that demonstrates what I'm doing](http://jsfiddle.net/QUP7t/)

I've added a style as well.

```
.picture-link{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```